# draw sprite in cocos2d useing openGL

Tags: opengl-es, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to draw a sprite using openGL like this:

```
- (void)draw
{       
    // Default GL states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY
    // Needed states: GL_VERTEX_ARRAY
    // Unneeded states: GL_COLOR_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY
    //glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    //glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    //glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, circleVertices_);
    //glColor4f(color_.r/255.0f, color_.g/255.0f, color_.b/255.0f, opacity_/255.0f);

    BOOL newBlend = NO;
    if( blendFunc_.src != CC_BLEND_SRC || blendFunc_.dst != CC_BLEND_DST ) {
        newBlend = YES;
        //glBlendFunc(blendFunc_.src, blendFunc_.dst);
    }else if( opacity_ == 255 ) {
        newBlend = YES;
        //glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
    }else{
        newBlend = YES;
        //glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }

    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, numberOfSegments);

    //if( newBlend )
    //  glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);

    // restore default GL state
    //glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    //glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

if I'll uncomment any `gl***`, build and run app, there will be a **muliple** open GL error:

> OpenGL error 0x0502 in -[CCTextureAtlas drawNumberOfQuads:fromIndex:]
>   472

what does this error means? **What am I doing wrong?** This is a part of **SneakyJoystick**

Comment: Put glGetError call after each of your gl*** call and verify that all of them returns GL_NO_ERROR.

Comment: I got this error multiple times (on every redrawing, more than 10 every second) puting `glGetError` seems only posts more of them: I cant see any different log messeges.